# Styles, font and js don't load on laravel deployed on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, public, shared-hosting

As mentioned above, styles, font and js don't load on laravel deployed on shared hosting. How does it look like on my localhost:

[image: localhost view]

And that's same code deployed on hosting:

[image: website view]
Where I take it from:

[image: folder],

And that's how I tell me code the path:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('styles/style.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/main-page.js') }}"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/agency-fb" rel="stylesheet">
```

First I thought it's just public folder not loading, but then I realised that the font isn't also loaded - which is taken from https link, not from my public folder. Any ideas?
My config/filesystems.php:

```
 'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

 'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],
```

That's my console log

[image]

When you open it, it's just a simple 404

[image]

which I know, I just don't know why is it 404.

I tried to deploy a laravel driven code on a shared hosting. How did I do it? install newest laravel throught installatron, copyed my files, required laravel/livewire, composer update, composer dump-autoload.

I think I've tried everything. changed AppServiceProvider.php content into

```
public function boot()
{
    if (env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

Messed with asset to private asset, literally  everything I found did not work. Maybe it's something wrong with my files structure? it looks like that:

[image]

Comment: Watch your browser's Network tool (in the Developer Tools) while the page is loading in the hosted environment, and observe what response you get to each of the requests to load these resources. Also check the Console for errors. That should give you some more info about the nature of the problem.

Comment: Ah sorry, you're right  - I forgot to include it. Check edit.

Comment: Are you sure you have pointed the domain to the ```public``` directory? And ```.htaccess``` is the same as Laravel default provided. And also need to check that the ```asset``` looks into the ```public``` else you have to use the ```url``` function.

Comment: Tried multiple things found on laracasts and stack overflow, none worked. I didn't touch .htaccess tho. How can I know wheter asset looks into the public, and what url should I provide? Throught my file manager I cna go into: this url: /domains/studiokam.pl/public_html/mati-page/public/styles/style.css, but I cannot search that into my brower, or inserting it into my code doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, modyfing .htaccess worked for me.  Inside of it:

```
# Prevent direct access to the "public" folder - redirect to root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /public/
RewriteRule ^public/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
# - but look for the file in the "public" folder
#   (ensure we are not already in the "public" folder)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]

# Rewrite "everything" to the "public" subdirectory if not already
# This ignores existing files/dirs in the document root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)
RewriteRule !^public/ public/%1

# Handle Front Controller... (as before)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Source: https://www.brixly.help/article/25-how-do-i-load-laravel-from-the-public-directory-using-htaccess